# What is the purpose of a zero length array in a struct?

Tags: c, linux

When I'm looking the Linux kernel code, found the below code:

```
   struct thread_info {
    struct task_struct  *task;
    struct exec_domain  *exec_domain;
    unsigned long       flags;
    __u32           status;
    __u32           cpu;
    int         preempt_count;
    mm_segment_t        addr_limit;
    struct restart_block    restart_block;
    void __user     *sysenter_return;
    unsigned long           previous_esp;
    __u8            supervisor_stack[0];
};
```

Notice that the last variable "supervisor_stack", it is a zero length array, what is the usage of it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think think that means zero length array, I think it means it is getting or retrieving the first value of the array.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's the pre-C99 version of a flexible array member, offered by GCC as an extension.

The C99 way is to define the flexible array member with empty brackets,

```
__u8  supervisor_stack[];
```

It's used to store data whose amount is not constant contiguous to the struct. Memory is allocated in the form

```
struct foo *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + whatever_is_needed);
```

In paragraph 18 of 6.7.2.1, the standard (draft N1570) describes them:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the
>   offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ
>   from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
>   it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.

Answer (score 18):

It's a common C hack to declare what can be called a variable length-array (where you define the size at allocation time

Example:

```
struct line {
   int length;
   char contents[0];
 };

 struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
   malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
 thisline->length = this_length;
```

This way you have a structure definition of your data, which also stores the array length for obvious convecience purposes, but you're not constrained by the fixed size that is usually associated with a struct

Example taken from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)  (also more info in there)