# bmiColors field of BITMAPINFO structure

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, struct

The `BITMAPINFO` structure has the following declaration

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO;
```

Why is the `RGBQUAD` array static? Why is it not a pointer?

Comment: Probably because is read directly from bitmap file, not from memory. But this is only my guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard trick to declare a *variable sized* struct. The color table never has just one entry, it has at least 2 for a monochrome bitmap, typically 256 for a 8bpp bitmap, etc.  Indicated by the bmiHeader.biClrUsed member.  So the actual size of the struct depends on the bitmap format.

Since the C language doesn't permit declaring such a data structure, this is the closest match.  Creating the structure requires malloc() to allocate sufficient bytes to store the structure, calculated from biClrUsed.  Then a simple cast to (BITMAPINFO*) makes it usable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter than it is static or not. The thing is, you'd still have to allocate enough memory for the palette. It is a RGBQuad because it stores only R, G, B, A and nothing more..

example:

```
for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    lpbmpinfo->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = some_r;
    lpbmpinfo->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = some_g;
    lpbmpinfo->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = some_b;
    lpbmpinfo->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand it. I thought to use BITMAPINFO as a variable. Now I get it, thanks everybody)

Answer (score 0):

**There's no `static` keyword in the declaration.** It's a completely normal struct member. It's used to declare a variable-sized struct with a single variable-sized array at the end

The size of the array is only known at compile time, but since [arrays of size 0 are forbidden in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9722632/995714) so we'll use `array[1]` instead. See the detailed explanation from MS' Raymond Chen in [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043)

On some compilers like GCC zero-length arrays are allowed as an extension so Linux and many other platforms usually use `array[0]` instead of `array[1]`

> Declaring zero-length arrays is allowed in GNU C as an extension. A zero-length array can be useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object:
>
> ```
> struct line {
>   int length;
>   char contents[0];
> };
>
> struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
>   malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
> thisline->length = this_length;
> ```
>
> [Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

In C99 a new feature called [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) was introduced. Since then it's better to use `array[]` for portability

```
struct vectord {
    size_t len;
    double arr[]; // the flexible array member must be last
};
```

See also

- [What is the purpose of a zero length array in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11733981/995714)
- [What's the need of array with zero elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14643406/995714)
- [Array of zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295027/995714)
- [Is empty array in the end of the structure a C standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22220263/995714)
- [What is the advantage of using zero-length arrays in C?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-advantage-of-using-zero-length-arrays-in-C)