# Is empty array in the end of the structure a C standard?

Tags: c

I have noticed that an empty array in the end of the structure is often used in open source projects:

```
typedef struct A
{
    ......
    void *arr[];
} A;
```

I want to know is this a C standard? Or only OK for gcc compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of C99, it is now a C standard. Pre-C99 compilers may not support it. The old approach was to declare a 1-element array, and to adjust the allocation size for that.

New way:

```
typedef struct A
{
    ......
    void *arr[];
} A;  

int slots = 3;
A* myA = malloc(sizeof(A) + slots*sizeof(void*));
myA->arr[2] = foo;
```

Old way:

```
typedef struct A
{
    ......
    void *arr[1];
} A;  

int slots = 3;
A* myA = malloc(sizeof(A) + (slots-1)*sizeof(void*));
myA->arr[2] = foo;
```

Comment: Is the following case possible? That is for data aligned, there are padding bytes in the end of struct A. so there is a gap between myA->arr[0] and myA->arr[1].

Comment: Padding can lead to allocating more memory than is actually needed, but it won't cause problems with the calculation of array slot addresses. If `sizeof(void*)==4`, then `arr[1]` will be four bytes after `arr[0]`, no matter how `A` is padded.

Comment: Nice catch, though. You're right, padding makes this technique a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

The standard (draft N1570) 18 of 6.7.2.1,  states:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a ﬂexible array member. In most situations,
>   the ﬂexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   ﬂexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. However, when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a ﬂexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the
>   offset of the array shall remain that of the ﬂexible array member, even if this would differ
>   from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
>   it had one element but the behavior is undeﬁned if any attempt is made to access that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.

Comment: Quoting the standard is good, but an explanation of why someone would do this and how it's used in practice would be nice.