# Struct with VLAs

Tags: c, pointers

How would I do the following for a `typedef` ?

```
typedef struct FriendStack {
    bool       is_resizable;
    size_t     max_size;
    Friend*    stack[];      // will have a variable length of friends
} FriendStack;
```

Is the way to convert this by doing `Friend**`, or how does that normally work?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? It's already a `typedef`. Is there an error? Or are you asking how to allocate memory for a variable of this type? Please clarify.

Comment: Well, both. Is it possible to do the above having `stack[]` without an explicit size?

Comment: This isn't a struct with VLAs. it's a struct with a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). anyway, please clarify your question. What you have is feasible and supported by C99 and later standards, a flexible sequence of `Friend*`. If you would rather abandon using a flexible member in favor of a member pointer to pointer you certainly can do that too.

Comment: The wording is unclear.  What do you mean by "do the above"?  You just did it.  What do you mean by "convert this": convert it to what, and in what sense?  "How does that normally work" - what is "that"?

Comment: @WhozCraig I see, I think that answers my question then, thanks for the feedback

Comment: "variable length of friends" --> Not quite.  That is a "variable length of "friends *".

Comment: @WhozCraig when I try and malloc though for that stack I get: `invalid use of flexible array member`. How do I malloc that data then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the need of array with zero elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643406/whats-the-need-of-array-with-zero-elements)

Comment: duplicate: [Is empty array in the end of the structure a C standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22220263/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sole purpose of using a *flexible array member* as the last member of a struct is to allow data of variable size to be appended directly after the struct in the same memory segment, and then access that data in a well-defined way.

That means that an array of pointers is often not what you want there, but rather an array of data. It *could* make sense in some special cases to allocate an array of pointers there, but if it does so in this case, I can't tell.

The normal use-case would be this:

```
typedef struct FriendStack {
    bool       is_resizable;
    size_t     max_size;
    Friend     stack[];
} FriendStack;

size_t n = something_variable;
FriendStack* fs = malloc( sizeof *fs + sizeof(Friend[n]) );
...
free(fs);
```

Now if the intention is to actually have `Friend* stack[]` instead, the syntax for allocating it is the same as above, except it becomes `sizeof(Friend*[n])` in malloc. And you'd need an additional loop to allocate something for each pointer:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  fs->stack[i] = malloc(...);
}
```

But unlike the first version, this creates segmented chunks in multiple locations on the heap, so it is significantly slower and the code turns more complex overall.