# Calculating malloc size of a tagged union (without over-allocating)

Tags: c, unions

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct MyObject {
    char* tag;
    union {
        BigObject b;     // imagine this is 5MB
        SmallObject s;   // imagine this is 8 bytes
    } u;
}
```

From the standard (copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740577/sizeof-a-union-in-c-c)):

> ...The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its data members. Each data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct.

Is there a way to get the exact size to `malloc` for a particular struct? It would be something like `tag*` (8) + padding (?) + [small or big object size] (?). In other words, how can I get what amounts to `MyObject o; sizeof(o)` which takes into account the proper `union`-ed object size?

Comment: This smells of an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) problem. It would work better if you explained what problem you are trying to solve, since this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @dxiv it's a conceptual question. That's why I made one member 5MB......

Comment: You can do exactly what you said -- use `sizeof(MyObject)`

Comment: @M.M I only want to alloc 16 bytes when I only need that much -- granted, this is a conceptual question and I'm just seeing if this type of thing is possible in C or if it's impossible.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 The concept here is that you cannot "slice" a struct like that in any safe or portable way. If you want to emulate inheritance in C, there are other ways that don't use a tagged union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When allocating memory for a structure, you **must** give enough space for the entire thing, even if you only use the smaller member of a containing union.

If you didn't allocate enough memory and you were to write to the larger member, you would invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for writing past allocated memory.  Even if you only wrote to the smaller member, there's no guarantee you wouldn't have a problem.

For example, if you did this:

```
MyObject *o1, *o2;
o1 = malloc(sizeof(char *) + sizeof(SmallObject)); 
o2 = malloc(sizeof(char *) + sizeof(SmallObject)); 
o1->tag = "small";
// assign values in o1.u.s
*o2 = *o1;
```

The assignment on the last line would trigger undefined behavior because the **entire** struct would be copied.

The way your struct is currently defined, best to just allocate `sizeof(struct MyObject)` bytes and be done with it.

As an alternative, you could instead have pointers to the containing structs and allocate space for them separately.

```
typedef struct MyObject {
    char* tag;
    union {
        BigObject *b;
        SmallObject* s;
    } u;
} MyObject;

...
MyObject *o = malloc(sizeof(MyObject));
o->tag = "big";
o->u.b = malloc(sizeof(BigObject));
```

Comment: right this is in the case where I manually handle the various struct members and never cross-convert, cast. etc.

Comment: an alternate way is to use a [flexible array member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618191/995714) at the end of the array that is in the same union. Of course memory must be allocated to contain enough the currently stored object