# Evaluate expression with stack

Tags: c++, stack

Hi I'm trying to write a program in c++ that evaluates expression using a stack but the result is a random number(an address memory maybe but it's not a pointer).
Here's the Stack template`

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
template <class Item>
class Stack {
public:
    static const size_t Capacity=100;
    Stack(){used=0;};
    void push(const Item& insert){data[used]=insert; used++;};
    void pop(){used--;};
    Item top(){return data[used-1];};
private:
    Item data[Capacity];
    size_t used;
};

#endif /* STACK_H_ */
`
```

and this is the main with the 2 functions used

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

double manage_stack(istream& insert);
void evaluate(Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operations);

int main(){
    double result;
    result=manage_stack(cin);
    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}

double manage_stack(istream& insert){
    double number;
    char symbol;
    Stack<double> numbers;
    Stack<char> symbols;
    while(insert.peek()!='\n'){
    if(isdigit(insert.peek())||insert.peek()=='.'){
        insert>>number;
        numbers.push(number);
    }
    else if(strchr("+-*/",insert.peek())!=NULL){
        insert>>symbol;
        symbols.push(symbol);
    }
    else if(insert.peek()==')')
        evaluate(numbers, symbols);
    else
        insert.ignore();
    }
    return numbers.top();
}

void evaluate(Stack<double> numbers, Stack<char> operations){
    double n1, n2;
    n2=numbers.top();
    numbers.pop();
    n1=numbers.top();
    numbers.pop();
    switch(operations.top()){
    case'+':numbers.push(n1+n2);
            break;
    case'-':numbers.push(n1-n2);
            break;
    case'*':numbers.push(n1*n2);
            break;
    case'/':numbers.push(n1/n2);
            break;
    }
    operations.pop();
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider what `used` refers to:  the element at the top of the stack, or the one just past the top.

Comment: Not seeing any signs of storage being allocated to `data`

Comment: `Item data[];` This is not legal C++ and certainly not an infinite array.

Comment: What did you see when you debugged your code?

Answer (score 3):

`Item data[];` is a non-standard extension and is being used improperly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733981/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-zero-length-array-in-a-struct) to see how it's supposed to be used. You haven't allocated any memory for it, as such you are in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Your program can have any behavior, including running and returning random values. For your application, you should consider using [std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) instead of your `Stack` class. It looks like you can substitute it directly.

```
#include <stack>
template<class T>
using Stack = std::stack<T>;
```

I've tried to run your example and the result is still incorrect, but it doesn't return random values. It always returns the first operand twice.

I've answered why the result appears random. If you want to know why your parser still doesn't give the correct result, I suggest using a debugger. There is a quite a bit of work left to do. For example, there doesn't seem to be any iteration over the input. You will need some sort of loop or recursion.

Comment: I've corrected the capacity of the stack and added the loop but still not properly working. I've edited with the new code

Comment: @Xdroid You never call `evaluate` in `manage_stack` if the user doesn't use parentheses. You should call evaluate on your stacks as long as the numbers stack contains more than 1 number at the end of `manage_stack`. The original question has been answered. If you have *new* problems, please use a debugger and create new question for problems you cannot solve yourself **and for which you cannot find existing ressources**. Prolonged Q&A on stackoverflow comments is not the best way to learn to program.