# Array with uninitialized size inside struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In the program

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct t {
        char a[5];
        char b[];
        } temp;

int main(){
        temp.b[0] = 'c';
        temp.b[1] =  'b';
        temp.b[2] = '\0';
        printf("Size of struct = %lu\n", sizeof(temp));
        printf("String is %s\n", temp.b);

        printf("Address of temp = %p\n", &temp);
        printf("Address of array a = %p\n", &(temp.a));
        printf("Address of b = %p\n", &(temp.b));
}
```

with output

```
Size of struct = 5
String is cb
Address of temp = 0x601035
Address of array a = 0x601035
Address of b = 0x60103a
```

In this program, how exactly is array b being allocated? How long is it? Is this some undefined behavior, which is only succeeding in the dummy program as I am not doing anything else. Running into gdb, I can access some memory locations initialized as zero, which makes me suspect that it is allocating some memory.

I do have an api that requires me to format one element of struct as int a[][SIZE], and I am confused about that.

Also, why is sizeof not taking into account at least something from array b. I am not sure if it is taking it as an array or pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11734035/669576

Comment: `b` is a flexible array member; introduced in C99.

Comment: what you have here is undefined behaviour. The open ended struct stuff people refer to above only works for malloced things. You have a static struct. You are writing off the end of it

Comment: Did you compile this? What does the compiler say? What's not obvious about the behaviour of the compiler? So, why do you ask at all?

Comment: @Olaf The compile compiled the program, without any errors or output. I saw the code like this, i.e. with array size as empty in structs, and was curious about memory allocation. The code I had sign had called an assembly call to fill the data struct, so I didn't see that it was allocating memory, hence I asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use it is **undefined behavior**. To answer your immediate question, with static or automatic storage (as you use it), this member has a size of `0`. So any index will be invalid. It "seems" to work in your experiment, but remember, [c](/questions/tagged/c) doesn't do any bounds checking. In fact, you're doing invalid writes and you're just lucky your example doesn't crash and burn.

Such a member is only allowed as **last** member of a structure and the reason for this is you can use it with dynamic storage:

```
struct t *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct t) + 5 * sizeof(char));
```

will allocate an instance of `struct t` with `temp->b` being an array of `char` of size 5.

Comment: note, it can also be used with other storage types by making a union with the struct and a char buffer. But dynamic allocation is the most common use.